# SIGABRT error on ios simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, slider

I use `viewcontrollers` with `Navigation Controller`. I press a `UIButton` on homescreeen and go another `viewcontroller`. When I click a `UIButton` on new `viewcontroller`, I go homescreen again. But when I press a `UIButto`n on homescreen, this time, it gives an error.

I created button with codes, not on storyboard.

What could be the problem?
Some friends say, `poptorootviewcontroller` solves the problem, but I dont know adding it to button.
Anyone can help?

here s a short video of it;
[image]

here is the code;

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     

    let closeButton = UIButton()
    closeButton.frame = CGRect(x: screen.width - 70, y: 20, width: 60, height: 60)
    closeButton.setTitle("Skip", forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5), forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OnboardingController2.pressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(closeButton)
}


func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    audioPlayer?.stop();
    let loginPageView =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomePage") as! ViewController
    self.presentViewController(loginPageView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I wonder how you are adding the action on the home screen. Show the code for the computer button, as the close button seems to be doing what it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace the below code in your `pressed` button action. because when you are skipping and going to home view controller. you are presenting the controller so navigation is no more in the stack. and again when you press on the computer button it will try to push the controller and because navigation is no more in the stack it is crashing. when you are pressing the skip button try to `pop` view controller. like below.

```
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    audioPlayer?.stop();
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    // OR
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```